# "set -e" and "test" in shell

Tags: shell, testing, set

In shell scripts set `-e` is often used to make them more robust by stopping the script when some of the commands executed from the script exits with non-zero exit code. I am confused about "`set -e`" and "`test`" commands, the result is contrary to what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
a=10
b=9
#test $a -lt $b && false
#test $a -gt $b && false
echo "111"
```

The real result is:
if `a > b`, print nothing
if `a < b`, print 111.
but i don't think so, i think the result is nothing whatever happened.

Comment: Adding `&& false` creates a command that is *guaranteed* to fail, no matter what `test` does.

Comment: @JackDai, it's strongly advisable to go through the exercises in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) before deciding to use `set -e` in real code.

Comment: oh snap! thanks @CharlesDuffy I've never seen BashFAQ, very nice

Comment: @chepner, ...re: "command guaranteed to fail" -- true, but because the left-hand side is "checked" (evaluated for flow-control purposes) it doesn't trigger an errexit when it fails. See https://ideone.com/iyUZ0N -- we get to the second `test` command despite the first one failing. (Of course, I *wholeheartedly* agree that depending on this for flow control is confusing to even an experienced reader and is best avoided).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote your script means, it will exit without printing anything in all situation BUT if a and b are equals.

If you try with `a = 9` and `b = 9`, you will see the `111` output.

You can easily all the behaviour, using the `-x` option of GNU/Bash.

The explanation of the exit, is your use of `-e` option; you can read this in [GNU/Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

Comment: I find the reasons in my answer,you can check it out.

Comment: I completed consequently my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit when `a` is greater than `b`, just write

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
a=10
b=9
test $a -le $b
echo "111"
```

If `test` fails, `set -e` will cause the script to exit; if it succeeds, the script continues to `echo`. However, there are many pitfalls to using `set -e`; I recommend just doing your own error handling.

```
#!/bin/bash

abort () { printf '%s\n' >&2; exit 1; }
a=10
b=9
test "$a" -le "$b" || abort "$a is greater than $b"
echo "111"
```

Comment: I find the reasons in my answer,you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i find the answer which is

> SHELL Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a  single  simple  com-mand), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not exit if the command that fails is  part of  the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, part of any  command executed  in  a  && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value  is being  inverted with !.